# Parse time string and convert it into a date object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, filter

I want to create a Date object in TypeScript (AngularJS) from this string: `08:00:00.000+01:00` in order to use a filter in the end to show only the hour and the minute:

```
.filter('toDate', () => {
    return input => {
        let date = Date.parse(input);
        return date;
    }
})
```

In the HTML:

```
{{ object.unformatedTimeString | toDate | date: 'H:m' }}
```

Does anyone know a good way how to parse such a time string?

Comment: Why don't you just pull the hour and minute from the string? `let [hr, min] = str.split(':');`. Why the conversion?

Comment: Because there is also timezone information in the time string. Better convert it correctly.

Comment: Have you considered using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)? It is much more versatile than javascripts date object.

Comment: @Igor it's also massive and complex. Worth it if you have a lot of date manipulations, but not necessarily for small stuff.

Comment: moment.js would be an option if it integrates nicely into AngularJS (1.6.x).

Comment: It is a standard javascript library. Add a reference to it on the page where you load angular.js library and you can use it across your scripts after that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Let [ts, tz] = str.split(/[\+\-]/);
let [hr, min] = ts.split(':').map(Number);
let offsetSign = str.includes('+') ? 1 : -1;
let [offsetHr, offsetMin] = tz.split(':');
let offset = offsetSign * ((offsetHr * 1000 * 60 * 60) + (offsetMin * 1000 * 60));

let date = new Date();
date.setHour(hr);
date.setMinute(min);
let result = new Date(date.getTime() + offset);
```

Tedious, but not complex or difficult.

Comment: There's no need to convert `[hr, min]` to Number as multiplication will convert them as required and you should do `date.setHour(hr, min, 0, 0)` to set the time in one go. This may return a Date before the current date, the OP should test thoroughly to ensure the logic is correct, it may need to set UTC hour and minute. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to adjust the time for the timezone, making it a UTC time, then apply it to the current UTC date, e.g.

```js
function parseToUTCTime(s) {
  var now = new Date();
  var b = s.match(/\d+|\D/g);
  var sign = b[7]=='+'? 1 : -1;
  now.setUTCHours(+b[0] + sign*b[8], +b[2] + sign*b[10], 0, 0);
  return now;
}

// Tests
['08:00:00.000+01:00',
 '06:30:00.000-08:00',
 '04:15:00.000+05:30'].forEach(ts =>
   console.log(ts + ' -> ' + parseToUTCTime(ts).toISOString())
 );
```